# ssh tunnelling local asp.net with srv.us not working

Tags: asp.net, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to tunnel my localhost:5001 which hosting my asp.net web app so that my colleague can access it but the url they provide always shows no response (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

I tested it using php and the tunnel is working fine.

are there any special configuration to tunnel asp.net web app?